# Redirect to different page based on choice in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently building a website for a client and need help with an issue.

The company offers services for both individuals and businesses so I built a "welcome page" where you can choose which one you're looking for.
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ddr.png)

After you make your choice you're taken to either the business homepage or individual homepage.

I want the browser to remember the choice the visitor makes so next time they're browsing the website they're automatically taken to either business or individual homepage.

Do you guys have any simple solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Use cookies :-)

Comment: You could use database to remember.

Comment: <a href="http:// www . google . com" />

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is to use cookies. Although it is easy to use/implement, there are certain legislation around cookie usage, depending on which country your page will be served.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

function setting_my_first_cookie() {
 setcookie( $v_choice, $v_value, 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}

?>
```

You can get more detailed info from [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/set-get-delete-cookies/)